# What is the right way to handle spaces between Column when dynamically adding children or passing a List? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I've seen a lot of posts on how to add spacing between children's Columns using SizedBox.

How do you go about spacing when you are dynamically adding children or just providing a List to the `Column()`?

A few thoughts I have in mind but not sure if it's the right way to do this:

- When you dynamically generate a child widget wrap the child in padding or container with margin.
- Create a function to automatically insert a SizedBox after generating a child
- Does it mean Wrap() is the right way to go instead of `Column()`?

What are your go-to ways of handling this?

Answer (score 1):

when your children are generated dynamically you should use `ListView.seperator`

```
ListView.separated(
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
  itemCount: 20,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Center(child: Text("Index $index")),
      ),
)
```

and `separatorBuilder` add height or width between your widgets